# What is the best way to ignore errors when importing data from a pandas data frame to SQL Server?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

I'm writing a python script to daily import data from a legacy system's data dump. I'd like to import the data and just skip rows that throw errors (e.g. wrong data-type). What is the best way of achieving this?

My current code:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)
conn = engine.connect()
df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
df.to_sql(tbl_name,conn,if_exists="append",index=False)
```

The file is rather large, so I'd prefer not iterating through rows as I have seen in some examples.

Comment: Sounds like a task for a proper ETL package, which can redirect failed rows.

Comment: @Larnu thank you! I guess that is the best way to go. Although I am still testing some other aspects of the system, so I would have liked a quick and easy work-around in the meantime

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't the `df.to_sql` just ignore those by default?  I thought that's how it worked.  If not, just setup a try catch routine.

```
try:
  engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)
  conn = engine.connect()
  df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
  df.to_sql(tbl_name,conn,if_exists="append",index=False)
catch:
  print('en erro was detected; please check...')
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but it doesn't ignore errors. Even with a try catch routine, the entire write fails. I'd like to just ignore the problem rows. As @Larnu mentioned, it is better to set up an ETL package

Comment: Ignoring errors could mean assign None to cells, not simply do not save the dataframe. Catch is not a python command.